# What's the name of the default ant config file name?

Tags: ant

Actually I'm a new to ant.  I want to know the name of the default ant config file name.  Is it build.xml or other name?  If is it can I change that name?  If so, how can I execute the script?

Comment: Please type your question into your favorite search engine before asking here. For this one, you'll get your answer _without even having to click on a link_, it'll be in the excerpts.

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ant/ant_build_files.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the default build file is `build.xml` in the current directory.

So if you execute

```
ant
```

Then ant will attempt to load build.xml in the current directory.

You can specify a file with a different name or location by specifying with the "-f" option, for example

```
ant -f ../other_dir/build.xml
```

or

```
ant -f special.xml
```